# Sponja on Shabbos - May one do it?

Tags: halacha, shabbat, cleaning

In Israel a popular way of cleaning floors is with [sponja](http://jhvonline.com/sponja-p13495-157.htm). Is there a way that one may do this on Shabbos? (sources)

Comment: That article about sponja is a pure delight.

Comment: What would be the problem?

Comment: @Loewian: Sechita, watering plants, not Kovod Shabbos

Comment: so Sponja is just Hebrew for squeegee? https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7SXgAS9kp3Y start at 37 seconds

Comment: Isn't it just a non-absorbent rubber strip? How would that be a problem of *sechita*? And I assume if the water won't be watering plants, that would be a way one may do it (Does it usually end up watering plants?) As far as kovod shabbos - is it that different than sweeping? (Though I suppose you could say there is more *tircha*... and it could always qualify for the ever-elusive catch-all category of *uvda d'chol*)

Comment: The problem of schita is with the smartut rizpah (coarse floor cloth) that is wrapped around the rubber bit and does the actual work of soaking up the water. It needs squeezing out to remove excess water. I suppose you could concievably find a solution for Shabbat, but the dividing line between permitted and forbidden could be so fine that in the end it would probably be forbidden. You also have nowadays one-time "cloths" with liquid in them. That could be a line to follow re Shabbat because there is no squeezing involved, just wiping over a surface.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I once told off the shames in Zichron Moshe stiebelach for doing sponja on Shabbos. He responded that Dayan Fisher had told him it was permissible so I should direct any further enquiries to the dayan.